# Paste text into UIWebView / website

Tags: html, swift, string, uiwebview, swift2

I'm loading a website into an `UIWebView`. This website includes a button and a textField. In the app itself i stored a string. Now I'd like to paste this string into the textField of the website (which has been loaded up in the `UIWebView`). Does someone know how I can do this in Swift? Thanks a lot for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`.

Assuming your website is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Hello world</title>
</head>
<body>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="" id="name">
</body>
</html>
```

You want to set the value in the name field to some user-entered value in your app:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    webView.delegate = self
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
   // This is the value you want to pass into the website, it can be something that
   // the user entered into your app. Here, I use a hard coded value for convenience
    let name = "John Smith"

   // Make sure the element's id in getElementById matches your HTML code
    var js = "var textfield = document.getElementById('name');\n"
    js += "textfield.value = '" + name + "';"

    webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(js)
}
```